# No test results

Tags: android, junit, android-espresso

Get next info message:

> Testing started at 12:26 PM ...
>
> 03/02 12:26:53: Launching 'All tests in app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8.
> Running tests
>
> $ adb shell CLASSPATH=$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process /
> androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -r -w -e
> targetInstrumentation
> com.mandarine.authenticator.tests/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
> --no-window-animation  -e package com.mandarine.authenticator.unitTests -e debug false androidx.test.orchestrator/androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator
>
> Started running tests
>
> Test running failed: No test results

But when I deleted this option, tests run:

```
testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}
```

**Update**:

Updated dependencies `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` , and get next error: Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

Get next error in Logcat:

> 2020-03-03 10:21:38.333 2869-2892/? E/AndroidTestOrchestrator: Fatal
> exception when setting up.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Permission requested but not granted!
> at androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator.grantRuntimePermissions(AndroidTestOrchestrator.java:231)
> at androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator.onStart(AndroidTestOrchestrator.java:201)
> at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2154)
> 2020-03-03 10:21:38.346 2869-2892/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> Instr: androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator
> Process: androidx.test.orchestrator, PID: 2869
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.Instrumentation.getContext()' on
> a null object reference
> at androidx.test.orchestrator.listeners.OrchestrationXmlTestRunListener.createOutputResultStream(OrchestrationXmlTestRunListener.java:253)
> at androidx.test.orchestrator.listeners.OrchestrationXmlTestRunListener.generateDocument(OrchestrationXmlTestRunListener.java:191)
> at androidx.test.orchestrator.listeners.OrchestrationXmlTestRunListener.orchestrationRunFinished(OrchestrationXmlTestRunListener.java:178)
> at androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator.finish(AndroidTestOrchestrator.java:443)
> at androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator.onStart(AndroidTestOrchestrator.java:210)
> at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2154)

Comment: as your using androidx (androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner) please change 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR' to 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'

Comment: this solution doesn't work for me

Comment: did you add this     androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.2.0'
along with the execution options ?

Comment: @LenaBru updated this dependencies and use `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` , and get next error: Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

Comment: please look in the error log of the logcat and tell me what it says

Comment: did you add the androidTestUtil Dependency? what is the version number of the orchestrator ?

Comment: @LenaBru androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.2.0'

Comment: Did you finally make it work?

Comment: There is a bug in Orchestrator https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72758547

Answer (score 4):

Delete app level build.gradle file's line, Does the trick.

```
testOptions {
execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}
```

Worked.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is `testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'`. It should work if you remove it.

This happens because there is a bug in Orchestrator (or Jacoco?): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72758547 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123987001.

I'm using `androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.3.0-beta01'` and still happens. I'm also waiting for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the test doesn't run on the below API versions:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.0'
```

Downgrading that to the following got the tests run

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
```